# How can I improve the drainage rate from a new walk-in shower?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

I've fitted a standalone shower in my bathroom. I had a bath with a shower over it previously, and we wanted a walk in.

The waste outlet to the sewer is in the same place, and I've connected it up to the shower waste trap. The problem is, there is very little (if any) slope from the shower to the sewer.

The outlet from the shower trap is almost the same height off the floor as the sewer inlet, giving me no chance of sloping it. I did think about raising the shower bed up, but we already put it on struts to accommodate the shower waste. Any higher and the trim wouldn't fit.

Anyway, I was wondering if there is anything I can do. Are there any products out there that would suck the water from the shower and spit it out the other end? Almost like the shower pump I have, gravity fed.

It does eventually drain, just slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the pitch would do little. It sounds like it may not be vented correctly.

Comment: It's connected to a bath waste with a t-junction and the bath empties as expected.